# Changing default file name download with JS?

Tags: javascript, button, download, filenames

How would I go about changing the name of a clip that is going to be downloaded by the client on a website? Each video clip currently downloaded is a default name how do I go about customising it?

Below is the function for the download button.

```
// Function to generate the Download button
VideoPlayer.prototype.initDownload = function () {

    var downloadBtn         = $("button.download"),
        downloadToolTipCls  = "download_tooltip",
        sources             = {},
        downloadToopTip,
        sourcesLength = 0,
        sourcesKeys;


    // Add each source
    if (typeof (firstSrc = this.$video.attr("src")) !== "undefined") {
        sources[firstSrc] = this.$video.attr("type");
    }

    this.$video.find("source").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        sources[$this.attr("src")] = $this.attr("type");
    });

    sourcesKeys = Object.keys(sources);
    sourcesLength = sourcesKeys.length;
    if (sourcesLength === 1) {
        downloadBtn.wrap("<a href=\"" + sourcesKeys[0] + "\" download />");
    } else if (sourcesLength > 1) {
        downloadBtn.after("<span class=\"" + downloadToolTipCls + "\" />");
        downloadToopTip = $("." + downloadToolTipCls);

        $.each(sources, function (source, type) {
            downloadToopTip.append("<a href=\"" + source + "\" download> Type " + type + "</a>");
        });

        downloadBtn.click(function () {
            downloadToopTip.toggle();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: The server has to set the filename in the `Content-Disposition` header.

Answer (score 0):

Put the name that you want for your file in download attribute `download=name`

Comment: What do you mean? In the code I sent or a separate file

Comment: In the download attribute of the anchor `<a download="name">`